# Bajar volumen a SKAudioNode en determinado tiempo

Tags: swift, swift3, spritekit

Estoy intentando bajar el volumen a un SKAudioNode mediante el siguiente código:

```
audioNode?.run(SKAction.changeVolume(to: 0.0, duration: 3.0 ))
```

Debería bajar el volumen a 0.0 en 3.0 segundos. Pero el sonido se detiene de inmediato.

¿Es posible hacer esto en SpriteKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la siguiente solución:

Swift 3:

```
extension SKAction  {  
  // All the change... actions for SKAudioNode are broken. They do not work with looped audio. These are replacements  
  
  public class func _changeVolumeTo(endVolume: Float, duration: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction  
       {  
       var startVolume : Float!  
       var distance : Float!  
  
   let action = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(duration)  
        {  
        node, elapsedTime in  

        if let soundNode = node as? SoundNode  
             {  
             if startVolume == nil  
                  {  
                  startVolume = soundNode.volume  
                  distance = endVolume - startVolume  
                  }  

             let fraction = Float(elapsedTime / CGFloat(duration))  
             let newVolume = startVolume + (distance * fraction)  

             soundNode.volume = newVolume  
             }  
        }  

   return action  
   }  
  }
```

[Fuente](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/44637?answerId=130390022#130390022)